# Storing image names as a list/array in selenium-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want store list of files path (image,video) in an array or a list.
Then I would like to choose any one path randomly, for uploading it.

Is it possible to do using selenium web-driver and python?

How can I randomly fetch one file from the directory?

Comment: Please, reformulate your question. You need to post some code and be more specific. The question is too broad.

Comment: @Yonatan : Thank you.
I tried doing with the help of using random. And it worked.

Here is the code:

#File common_settings
ImgDir=os.path.abspath('.\\resources\\Images')
Image_Path, Image_name=CommonFunctions.RandomImageFetch(ImgDir)


#File Common_functions
def RandomImageFetch(ImgDir):
        filename = random.choice(os.listdir(ImgDir))
        path = os.path.join(ImgDir, filename)        
        return (path, filename)

Answer (score 0):

this may differ from site to site but generally this should work

```
from random import choice
list_of_files = ['some.jpg', 'thing.jpg']
random_file = choice(list_of_files)

import requests
r = requests.post('http://your-site.org/post', files={random_file: open(random_file, 'rb')})
```

recommend reading about "post" using python requsts - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

wouldn't recommend using selenium for that

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing with the help of using random. And it worked.

Here is the code:

File common_settings

```
ImgDir=os.path.abspath('.\\resources\\Images')
Image_Path, Image_name=CommonFunctions.RandomImageFetch(ImgDir)
```

File Common_functions

```
def RandomImageFetch(ImgDir):        
filename = random.choice(os.listdir(ImgDir))        
path = os.path.join(ImgDir, filename)        
return (path, filename)
```